# Database Structure for football match

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a database for football odds.

I have table odds with :

ID
HomeID
AwayID
Odds

And a table store all football team name call team:

ID
Name

I would like have a query that display :

ID
HomeName
AwayName
Odds

Are there any ways to make a query like that ?
Or i need to split the team table to 2 tables like : HomeTeam, AwayTeam ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One table named team will do.  The home and away IDs are foreign keys that reference the primary key ID in the team table.

Your proposed design isn't normalized.  You should not be repeating data, as you'd have to if you had separate home and away team tables.

```
create table team (
    id int not null,
    name varchar(20) not null,
    primary key(id)
);

create table odds (
    home_id int not null,
    away_id int not null,
    odds varchar(20) not null,
    primary key(home_id, away_id),
    foreign key(home_id) references team(id),
    foreign key(away_id) references team(id)
);

select h.name, a.name, o.odds
from odds as o
join team as h
join team as a
on o.away_id = a.id
on o.home_id = h.id
where h.name = 'home team name' 
and a.name = 'away team name'
```

Comment: Could you please help me if i use one table team, how the query string look like ?